# How do I provide mocha a callback to be invoked upon a test timeout?

Tags: mocha.js

*NB: This is the simplest example that demonstrates the issue.  My use case is more complex.*

How do I receive a callback if a mocha test times out?

For example, if I have a function

```
const myCallback = () => { console.log('my test timed out') }
```

and a test

```
describe('stuff', () => {
  it('will timeout', function(done) {
    this.timeout(100)
    setTimeout(done, 200)
  })
})
```

how do I instruct mocha to invoke `myCallback` when the test times out?